# Datediff in columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datediff

I am wanting to use the datediff function in mySQL but my code its returning Nulls and I think its because the columns that I am using have a format of MM/DD/YYYY. How could I over come this. This is the code that I have.

```
select p.`Brand.Name`, datediff( 'p.`Pdo.Date`', 'f.`EntryDate`') from packaging as p
join volumes as v using(batchNum)
join fermentation as f on v.`LineNum` = f.`QC.LineId` 
group by `Brand.Name`;
```

Comment: What is the type of the date columns? If it is a varchar you should change it into date

Comment: Oh I see. It is as TEXT

Comment: And don't have columns formatted as mdy

Comment: @Strawberry So since the format of my data is dd/mm/yyyy I can not just simply change my data type to date since it has to be in yyyy-mm-dd I have now used this code to reformat it as a select statement:
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`Date.Tested`,'%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') as DateFormat from airtest;

But do you know how I can alter the column and change the format of my values to yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: You don't need DATE_FORMAT() here; once you've correctly reformatted the dates, you can just redefine the column with the correct data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert your text to a date

```
select p.`Brand.Name`, datediff( STR_TO_DATE(`p`.`Pdo.Date`,"%m/%d/%Y"), STR_TO_DATE(`f`.`EntryDate`,"%m/%d/%Y")) 
from packaging as p
join volumes as v using(batchNum)
join fermentation as f on v.`LineNum` = f.`QC.LineId` 
group by `Brand.Name`;
```

Comment: Nice yes this works and I dont have to change the data type. If I wanted to change the data type to date is there a way I can do that while also change the current format to yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: you have to use the same STR_TO _DATE to rewrite all your rows, and the change the data type, but as always first a **backup before** changing anything